# Create AWS RDS Instance with specific version?

Tags: .net, wpf, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-sdk-net

I am attempting to create an AWS RDS database. Any engine would be OK.

```
rdsClient = new Amazon.RDS.AmazonRDSClient(<aws_credentials>, <some_region>);

try
{
    rdsClient.CreateDBInstance(new CreateDBInstanceRequest(identifier, allocatedStorage, instanceSize, engine, username, password));
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} was succesfully created!", identifier));
}
catch (AmazonRDSException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

So I am loading my credentials into an RDS Client and attempting to create a database. This works fine except I cannot specify a database version. Is there any alternative way of creating a database or specifying a version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself yet, but I think you would want to do something like this (the capitalization below is almost certainly wrong):

```
var dbr = new CreateDBInstanceRequest();

   dpr.EngineVersion = <yourvalue>;
   dbr.Identifier = <yourvalue>;
   dbr.AllocatedStorage = <yourvalue>;
   dbr.InstanceSize = <yourvalue>;
   dbr.Engine = <yourvalue>;
   dbr.Username = <yourvalue>;
   dbr.Password = <yourvalue>;
   //also set any other values

 try
        {
            rdsClient.CreateDBInstance(dbr);
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} was succesfully created!", identifier));
        }
        catch (AmazonRDSException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Services/RDS/Generated/Model/CreateDBInstanceRequest.cs

Comment: thank you I have no idea why I didnt think of that -_-